# Using lists and user-generated to run specific commands on multiple variables and datasets

Tags: r, list, variables, dataset, iteration

I want to use lists and user-generated to run specific commands on multiple variables and datasets.

For examples, I want to turn the `table`, `cut`, and `color` variables into factors using the `as.factor(as.character())` command in R on 3 different datasets, `diamonds`, `diamonds_bottom300`, and `diamonds_top300`, with the results being put into 3 new and user specified datasets called `diamonds_post`, `diamonds_bottom300_post`, and `diamonds_top300_post`.

I can do this the long way:

```
## long way to turn data into factors

### individually

#### for diamonds dataset
diamonds_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$table))
diamonds_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$cut))
diamonds_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$color))

#### for diamonds_bottom300 dataset
diamonds_bottom300_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$table))
diamonds_bottom300_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$cut))
diamonds_bottom300_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$color))

#### for diamonds_top300 dataset
diamonds_top300_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$table))
diamonds_top300_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$cut))
diamonds_top300_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$color))

## gives str of datasets
str(diamonds_post)
str(diamonds_top300_post)
str(diamonds_top300_post)

> ## gives str of datasets
> str(diamonds_post)
'data.frame':   53940 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ carat  : num  0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31 0.24 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 ...
 $ cut    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Fair","Good",..: 3 4 2 4 2 5 5 5 1 5 ...
 $ color  : Factor w/ 7 levels "D","E","F","G",..: 2 2 2 6 7 7 6 5 2 5 ...
 $ clarity: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 2 3 5 4 2 6 7 3 4 5 ...
 $ depth  : num  61.5 59.8 56.9 62.4 63.3 62.8 62.3 61.9 65.1 59.4 ...
 $ table  : Factor w/ 127 levels "43","44","49",..: 31 91 116 61 61 51 51 31 91 91 ...
 $ price  : int  326 326 327 334 335 336 336 337 337 338 ...
 $ x      : num  3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
 $ y      : num  3.98 3.84 4.07 4.23 4.35 3.96 3.98 4.11 3.78 4.05 ...
 $ z      : num  2.43 2.31 2.31 2.63 2.75 2.48 2.47 2.53 2.49 2.39 ...
> str(diamonds_top300_post)
'data.frame':   327 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ carat  : num  0.23 0.86 0.84 0.7 0.76 0.57 0.74 0.91 0.98 0.71 ...
 $ cut    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Fair","Good",..: 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ color  : Factor w/ 7 levels "D","E","F","G",..: 2 2 4 4 4 2 3 5 2 1 ...
 $ clarity: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 5 2 3 7 5 7 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ depth  : num  56.9 55.1 55.1 58.8 59 58.7 61.1 61.3 53.3 56.9 ...
 $ table  : Factor w/ 12 levels "65","65.4","66",..: 1 6 4 3 7 3 5 4 4 1 ...
 $ price  : int  327 2757 2782 2797 2800 2805 2805 2825 2855 2858 ...
 $ x      : num  4.05 6.45 6.39 5.81 5.89 5.34 5.82 6.24 6.82 5.89 ...
 $ y      : num  4.07 6.33 6.2 5.9 5.8 5.43 5.75 6.19 6.74 5.84 ...
 $ z      : num  2.31 3.52 3.47 3.44 3.46 3.16 3.53 3.81 3.61 3.34 ...
> str(diamonds_top300_post)
'data.frame':   327 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ carat  : num  0.23 0.86 0.84 0.7 0.76 0.57 0.74 0.91 0.98 0.71 ...
 $ cut    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Fair","Good",..: 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ color  : Factor w/ 7 levels "D","E","F","G",..: 2 2 4 4 4 2 3 5 2 1 ...
 $ clarity: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 5 2 3 7 5 7 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ depth  : num  56.9 55.1 55.1 58.8 59 58.7 61.1 61.3 53.3 56.9 ...
 $ table  : Factor w/ 12 levels "65","65.4","66",..: 1 6 4 3 7 3 5 4 4 1 ...
 $ price  : int  327 2757 2782 2797 2800 2805 2805 2825 2855 2858 ...
 $ x      : num  4.05 6.45 6.39 5.81 5.89 5.34 5.82 6.24 6.82 5.89 ...
 $ y      : num  4.07 6.33 6.2 5.9 5.8 5.43 5.75 6.19 6.74 5.84 ...
 $ z      : num  2.31 3.52 3.47 3.44 3.46 3.16 3.53 3.81 3.61 3.34 ...
```

I tried to create a user-generated function to do this task, and also a corresponding list:

```
### creates function to turn into numeric form
function_turn_dataset_variable_into_factor_form <- 
  # ---- NOTE: turns variable into sum contrasted version of variable
  # ---- NOTE: variable_name ==  variable to be turned to sum contrast
  # ---- NOTE: dataset_name == dataset that contains variable name
  # ---- NOTE: generally speaking, procedure is to create new variable with "_c" as suffix for corresponding sum contrasted variable
  function(variable_name, dataset_name)
  {
    # ---- NOTE: # changes variable_name and dataset_name to object
    colmn1 <- variable_name
    nm1 <- dataset_name
    # ---- NOTE: inserts dataset into function
    dataset_funct_object_A <- 
      data.frame(
        get(nm1)
      )
    # ---- NOTE: transdorms data into factor form
    dataset_funct_object_A[[colmn1]] <- as.factor(as.character(dataset_funct_object_A[[colmn1]]))
    # ---- NOTE: returns appropriate object
    return(dataset_funct_object_A)
  }


# ---- NOTE: dataset with lists of corresponding variables/dfs
variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  variable_to_become_factors datasets_to_become_factors datasets_post          
  <chr>                      <chr>                      <chr>                  
1 color                      diamonds                   diamonds_post          
2 color                      diamonds_bottom300         diamonds_bottom300_post
3 color                      diamonds_top300            diamonds_top300_post   
4 cut                        diamonds                   diamonds_post          
5 cut                        diamonds_bottom300         diamonds_bottom300_post
6 cut                        diamonds_top300            diamonds_top300_post   
7 table                      diamonds                   diamonds_post          
8 table                      diamonds_bottom300         diamonds_bottom300_post
9 table                      diamonds_top300            diamonds_top300_post
```

It does work when I use it individually, although it's not really faster to use the function than it is when I use the long way.

```
### runs user generated function on 1 variable/dataset
# ---- NOTE: gives structure of data
str(diamonds_post$color)
# ---- NOTE: runs function
diamonds_post <- function_turn_dataset_variable_into_factor_form(variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$variable_to_become_factors[1],variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$datasets_to_become_factors[1])
# ---- NOTE: gives structure of data
str(diamonds_post$color)
# ---- NOTE: works
# ---- NOTE: not really much faster than the long way
```

I can't really get it to work in the way that I want it when I apply it to lists using mapply(). Is there any way to get this task to work using a user generated function that returns the transformed variables to correspoding user specificed datasets that are different than the start dataset?

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

---

---

Here is the code used for the example:

```
# Loads packages
# ---- NOTE: making plots and diamonds dataset
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
# ---- NOTE: run mixed effects models
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")}
# ---- NOTE: for data wrangling
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}




# dataset creation

## for dataset with top 300 rows
# ---- NOTE: selects only the top 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_top300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, 300, table))
# ---- NOTE: gives dataset info
head(diamonds_top300)
str(diamonds_top300)
colnames(diamonds_top300)
nrow(diamonds_top300)
# ---- NOTE: gives unique values of Fixed and Random effects, and dvs
unique(diamonds_top300$price)
unique(diamonds_top300$y)
unique(diamonds_top300$cut)
unique(diamonds_top300$color)
unique(diamonds_top300$carat)
unique(diamonds_top300$clarity)
unique(diamonds_top300$depth)
unique(diamonds_top300$table)


## for dataset with bottom 300 rows
### dataset
# ---- NOTE: selects only the bottom 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_bottom300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, -300, table))
# ---- NOTE: gives dataset info
head(diamonds_bottom300)
str(diamonds_bottom300)
colnames(diamonds_bottom300)
nrow(diamonds_bottom300)
# ---- NOTE: gives unique values of Fixed and Random effects, and dvs
unique(diamonds_bottom300$price)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$y)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$cut)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$color)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$carat)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$clarity)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$depth)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$table)

### creates end result variables
diamonds_post <- data.frame(diamonds_bottom300)
diamonds_top300_post <- data.frame(diamonds_top300)
diamonds_bottom300_post <- data.frame(diamonds_bottom300)


# turns variables into factor for using as.factor(as.character()) command

## data frame with transformation info

### creates list of variable names to turn into factors
variable_to_become_factors <- 
  data.frame(
    variable_to_become_factors = c("table", "cut", "color")
  )

### creates list of data frames for transformation
datasets_to_become_factors <- 
  data.frame(
    datasets_to_become_factors = c("diamonds", "diamonds_bottom300", "diamonds_top300"),
    datasets_post = c("diamonds_post", "diamonds_bottom300_post", "diamonds_top300_post")
  )

### creates dataframe with all possible combinations of data
variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets <- 
  tidyr::crossing(variable_to_become_factors, datasets_to_become_factors)

### splits variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets data frame by data frame name
# ---- NOTE: creates list
variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets_list <- split(variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets, variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$datasets_to_become_factors)
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets_list <- 
  setNames(variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets_list, paste("variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_dataset", 
                                                                       datasets_to_become_factors$datasets_to_become_factors,
                                           sep = "__")
  )
# ---- NOTE: creates unique objects for each part list object
list2env(variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets_list, .GlobalEnv)
# ---- NOTE: gathers objects with prefix
apropos("variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_dataset")

## long way to turn data into factors

### individually

#### for diamonds dataset
diamonds_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$table))
diamonds_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$cut))
diamonds_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$color))

#### for diamonds_bottom300 dataset
diamonds_bottom300_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$table))
diamonds_bottom300_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$cut))
diamonds_bottom300_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_bottom300$color))

#### for diamonds_top300 dataset
diamonds_top300_post$table <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$table))
diamonds_top300_post$cut <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$cut))
diamonds_top300_post$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds_top300$color))

## gives str of datasets
str(diamonds_post)
str(diamonds_top300_post)
str(diamonds_top300_post)

## medium way

### creates function to turn into numeric form
function_turn_dataset_variable_into_factor_form <- 
  # ---- NOTE: turns variable into sum contrasted version of variable
  # ---- NOTE: variable_name ==  variable to be turned to sum contrast
  # ---- NOTE: dataset_name == dataset that contains variable name
  # ---- NOTE: generally speaking, procedure is to create new variable with "_c" as suffix for corresponding sum contrasted variable
  function(variable_name, dataset_name)
  {
    # ---- NOTE: # changes variable_name and dataset_name to object
    colmn1 <- variable_name
    nm1 <- dataset_name
    # ---- NOTE: inserts dataset into function
    dataset_funct_object_A <- 
      data.frame(
        get(nm1)
      )
    # ---- NOTE: transdorms data into factor form
    dataset_funct_object_A[[colmn1]] <- as.factor(as.character(dataset_funct_object_A[[colmn1]]))
    # ---- NOTE: returns appropriate object
    return(dataset_funct_object_A)
  }

### runs user generated function on 1 variable/dataset
# ---- NOTE: gives structure of data
str(diamonds_post$color)
# ---- NOTE: runs function
diamonds_post <- function_turn_dataset_variable_into_factor_form(variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$variable_to_become_factors[1],variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$datasets_to_become_factors[1])
# ---- NOTE: gives structure of data
str(diamonds_post$color)
# ---- NOTE: works
# ---- NOTE: not really much faster than the long way

### use mapply on individual lists
# ---- NOTE: applies functions to appropriate variables
function_test_object <- 
  mapply(function_turn_dataset_variable_into_factor_form, 
         variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$variable_to_become_factors, variable_to_become_factors_in_specific_datasets$datasets_to_become_factors, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# ---- NOTE: does not work as desired
```

EDIT 1:

Results from commenter "Ronak Shah":

This didn't seem to work; it's probably because of my own ignorance with R.

Here were the steps:

1. Run all of the code associated with the "Here is the code used for the example:" portion of the original post (not displayed).
2. Run commenter's script (didn't work for me):

```
> #Define the columns to change
> cols <- c('table', 'cut',  'color')
> cols
[1] "table" "cut"   "color"
> #Define the names of the dataframe to change
> original_names <- c('diamonds', 'diamonds_bottom300', 'diamonds_top300')
> original_names
[1] "diamonds"           "diamonds_bottom300" "diamonds_top300"   
> #New names of the changed dataframe
> new_names <- paste0(original_names, '_post')
> new_names
[1] "diamonds_post"           "diamonds_bottom300_post" "diamonds_top300_post"   
> #apply function to each column in each dataframe
> lapply(mget(original), function(x) {
+   x[cols] <- lapply(x[cols], function(y) as.factor(as.character(y)))
+   x
+ }) -> result
Error in mget(original) : object 'original' not found
> result
Error: object 'result' not found
> #Write to global environment. 
> names(result) <- new_names
Error in names(result) <- new_names : object 'result' not found
> list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
Error in list2env(result, .GlobalEnv) : object 'result' not found
```

Upon close inspection, it could have not worked because one of the calls was written as "original", not "original_names". Here is the results of this change:

```
> #Define the columns to change
> cols <- c('table', 'cut',  'color')
> cols
[1] "table" "cut"   "color"
> #Define the names of the dataframe to change
> original_names <- c('diamonds', 'diamonds_bottom300', 'diamonds_top300')
> original_names
[1] "diamonds"           "diamonds_bottom300" "diamonds_top300"   
> #New names of the changed dataframe
> new_names <- paste0(original_names, '_post')
> new_names
[1] "diamonds_post"           "diamonds_bottom300_post" "diamonds_top300_post"   
> #apply function to each column in each dataframe
> lapply(mget(original_names), function(x) {
+   x[cols] <- lapply(x[cols], function(y) as.factor(as.character(y)))
+   x
+ }) -> result
Error: value for ‘diamonds’ not found
> result
Error: object 'result' not found
> #Write to global environment. 
> names(result) <- new_names
Error in names(result) <- new_names : object 'result' not found
> list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
Error in list2env(result, .GlobalEnv) : object 'result' not found
```

Not sure what to do. Any advice for a fix could help. It could be my own fault, and I'm just not seeing the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#Define the columns to change
cols <- c('table', 'cut',  'color')
#Define the names of the dataframe to change
original_names <- c('diamonds', 'diamonds_bottom300', 'diamonds_top300')
#New names of the changed dataframe
new_names <- paste0(original_names, '_post')
#apply function to each column in each dataframe
lapply(mget(original), function(x) {
  x[cols] <- lapply(x[cols], function(y) as.factor(as.character(y)))
  x
}) -> result

#Write to global environment. 
names(result) <- new_names
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Check the output for one dataframe -

```
str(diamonds_post)

#tibble [53,940 × 10] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ carat  : num [1:53940] 0.23 0.21 0.23 0.29 0.31 0.24 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 ...
# $ cut    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Fair","Good",..: 3 4 2 4 2 5 5 5 1 5 ...
# $ color  : Factor w/ 7 levels "D","E","F","G",..: 2 2 2 6 7 7 6 5 2 5 ...
# $ clarity: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "I1"<"SI2"<"SI1"<..: 2 3 5 4 2 6 7 3 4 5 ...
# $ depth  : num [1:53940] 61.5 59.8 56.9 62.4 63.3 62.8 62.3 61.9 65.1 59.4 ...
# $ table  : Factor w/ 127 levels "43","44","49",..: 31 91 116 61 61 51 51 31 91 91 ...
# $ price  : int [1:53940] 326 326 327 334 335 336 336 337 337 338 ...
# $ x      : num [1:53940] 3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
# $ y      : num [1:53940] 3.98 3.84 4.07 4.23 4.35 3.96 3.98 4.11 3.78 4.05 ...
# $ z      : num [1:53940] 2.43 2.31 2.31 2.63 2.75 2.48 2.47 2.53 2.49 2.39 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do this on my comp, but it didn't seem to work, nor did it when I tried with different data. This is probably because of my own failures.

Comment: @Mel What do you mean by doesn't work? The columns defined in `cols` are converted to factor for each of the dataframe whose name is in `original_names`. The new dataframes are created with the name in `new_names`. Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work along with your reason for downvote?

Comment: I'm still working on the downvote use (new to the site), so I'm not sure what the etiquette is for downvotes. I was under the impression that you gave downvotes for code that didn't work on your console. I'll put my script in the text, since the comment characters are limited.